# Clojure Print the contents of a vector

Tags: clojure

In Clojure, how do you print the contents of a vector? (I imagine to the console, and usually for debugging purposes). If the answer can be generalized to any Seq that would be good.

**Edit:**
I should add that it should be a simple function that gives output that looks reasonable, so prints an item per line - so can be easily used for debugging purposes. I'm sure there are libraries that can do it, but using a library really does seem like overkill.

Answer (score 8):

I usually use `println`.  There are several other printing functions that you might want to try.  See the "IO" section of the [Clojure cheatsheet](http://clojure.org/cheatsheet).

This isn't Java.  Just print it, and it will look OK.

You can also use `clojure.pprint/pprint` to pretty-print it.  This can be helpful with large, complex data structures.

These methods work for all of the basic Clojure data structures.

Exception: Don't print infinitely long lazy structures such as what `(range)` returns--for obvious reasons.  For that you may need to code something special.

Comment: Thanks for the cheatsheet advice. It seems that http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.pprint/print-table is what I'm after

Comment: `print-table` is specifically for printing a sequence of Clojure maps.  If that's what you have (or can convert into), it might be perfect.

Comment: I substituted `print-table` for my simple hand-written one but just got `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.util.Map$Entry`.

Comment: `prn` is almost always better than `println` for examining clojure objects. `println` uses java's `toString`, which has different design goals than clojure data structures and so you can get misleading output. For example, `["a b c"]` and `[a b c]` are indistinguishable with `println`.

Comment: Thanks @amalloy. I didn't realize that.

Comment: Chris, about the exception, see my first comment.  It sounds like you tried to use `print-table` on a sequence of integers.

Comment: Or rather, you tried to use `print-table` on a sequence of sequences of integers.  (In some special contexts it's possible to treat a vector like it's a map.  Not this one, apparently.)

Answer (score 3):

This works for me:

```
(defn pr-seq
  ([seq msg]
   (letfn [(lineify-seq [items]
                        (apply str (interpose "\n" items)))]
     (println (str "\n--------start--------\n"
                   msg "\nCOUNT: " (count seq) "\n"
                   (lineify-seq seq) "\n---------end---------"))))
  ([seq]
    (pr-seq seq nil)))
```

Example usages:

```
(pr-seq [1 2 3])
(pr-seq (take 20 blobs) (str "First 20 of " (count blobs) " Blobs")))
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to just print out the elements of the sequence/vector you could just `map` `println` to your sequence/vector, but make sure you force `map` to evaluate using `dorun`:

```
(dorun (map println [1 2 3 4]))
```

This can be applied to sequences too:

```
(dorun (map println '(1 2 3 4)))
```

Another way you can do this with `apply` is to curry `map` with `println` and `apply` it to the sequence/vector:

```
(apply (partial map println) [[1 2 3 4]])
(apply (partial map println) ['(1 2 3 4)])
```

Another way you can do this is with `doseq`:

```
(doseq [e [1 2 3 4]]
  (println e))
(doseq [e '(1 2 3 4)]
  (println e))
```

Answer (score 1):

This one at least stops the text going out too far to the right:

```
(defn pp
  ([n x]
   (binding [pp/*print-right-margin* n]
     (-> x clojure.pprint/pprint)))
  ([x]
   (pp 100 x)))
```

It is possible to do `partial`s of this function to alter the width.